# How can I fill the Django forms field in view?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

In my Django forms I have 5 fields but I will take 4 of them from the html template. The 5. one will be filled in the views. When I try to do like this it says form is not valid. How can I fill the data in views?

**forms.py**

```
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = ProductModel
        fields = ('category','brand','series','model','asin')
```

**productform.html**

```
  <form id="firstform" action="{% url 'productpage' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" id="category" name="category" placeholder="Category">
    <input type="text" id="brand" name="brand" placeholder="Brand">
    <input type="text" id="series" name="series" placeholder="Series">
    <input type="text" id="model" name="model" placeholder="Model">

    <input type="submit" id="save-button" name="save-button" value="Save" >
  </form>
```

**views.py**

```
def productpage(request):

    if request.POST.get('save-button'):
        form = ProductForm()
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = ProductForm(data=request.POST)

            if form.is_valid():

                form.cleaned_data["asin"] = "B324235252"
                form.save()
                HttpResponse("SAVED")
            else:
                print("iiii")
                HttpResponse("Form is not valid")
        else:
            form = ProductForm()
    return render(request,"first_app/productform.html")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exclude the field from the form:

```
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = ProductModel
        fields = ('category','brand','series','model')  # 🖘 no asin
```

and then fill it in the view:

```
def productpage(request):
    if request.POST.get('save-button'):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = ProductForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.instance.asin = 'B324235252'
                form.save()
                HttpResponse("KAYDEDİLDİ")
    return render(request, 'first_app/productform.html')
```